# Why can't i use this?

Tags: php

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Web search,<?php echo $meta ?>" />
```

is there anything wrong in that.I'm not getting the output ...thats why !!

Comment: @Dalen the semicolon is not needed there.

Comment: Please provide the output of `var_dump($meta)`.

Comment: $meta could be anything, it could be html, breaking the meta tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Web search,<?php echo "[$meta]"; ?>" />.
```

That way you can check your source and if u see

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Web search,[]" />
```

then you know $meta was empty all along but the echo function is working fine.

Comment: +0 Seriously, what makes you think that the `echo` function is not working properly? Before trying to rule out an error in a native PHP function that has been around since forever, the OP could simply use `var_dump($meta)` to see what it contains.

Comment: My mistake, echo always works. Just use it to see if $meta is empty then. If you read up you'll see a lot of confusion as to if the PHP is actually executing. This would remove that confusion by showing that the PHP is being executed. var_dump() would work just as well ofcourse. :)

Comment: If the PHP wasn't executing the output would be literal, e.g. the Meta content would contain the string `<?php echo $meta ?>`. If this is not the case, it is almost certain that `$meta` is empty. The OP just needs to confirm this.